# display rails id in new form text_field rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to create a form in my `order` model. i've been wondering. can i display a new `order_id` in my `order_number` text field when creating new order??? i try

```html
<%= form_for(@order, html: {class: 'form form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :staff_id %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.collection_select :staff_id, Staff.all, :id, :staff_name, {:prompt => false}%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :customer_id %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :customer_name, {:prompt => false}%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :service_id %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.collection_select :service_id, Service.all, :id, :service_type, {:prompt => false}%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :order_number %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :order_number , :value => @order.id %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :order_vehicle %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :order_vehicle %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :order_plate %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :order_plate %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :order_description %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :order_description %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :order_damage %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :order_damage %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :order_deposit %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.number_field :order_deposit %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :order_price %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.number_field :order_price %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :order_date %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.date_select :order_date %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label "List of task" %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.collection_check_boxes :task_ids, Task.all, :id, :task_name do |b| %>
    <div class="collection-check-box">
      <%= b.check_box %>
      <%= b.label %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
        </td>
        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.submit %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<% end %>
```

in the form when creating new order it show nothing.

the `id` only appear when im editing the `order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` is generated after created. It should be a primary key in database table, and auto increase. In my option, the order number should generated by the system, and users can not modify it.

you can add a `after_create` observer to set the order_number

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_order_number
  def set_order_number
    self.update_attribute('order_number', self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: i see. i try to use your suggestion but rails keep giving me undefined method `after_create' for OrdersController:Class . can i use count+1 to display the id??

Comment: you should add the observer at Order model. on the other hand. yes, you can add something like  `<%= f.text_field :order_number , :value => @order.id || Order.last.id+1 %>` in view. but it is not threadsafe. And it may be duplicated.

Comment: It will work only when you won't delete any of rows from table. Single delete operation would corrupt it. Yes, Order.last.id+1 is fine.

Comment: ahh. sorry my bad, no wonder it got error. im gonna use your method. thx mate!